# How can an attacker use SQL injection in ALTER query?/What can an attacker do with an injectable ALTER statement?

Tags: sql-injection, owasp, secure-coding, oracle

Let's say you have a Java app which has a query which can [unlock/reset passwords](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/axdbi/using-sql-plus-to-unlock-accounts-and-reset-passwords.html#GUID-1147D2B9-8FFC-4F91-A774-E97066B4E9C5) for users like:

```
ALTER USER " + iD_Of_User.toUpperCase() + " IDENTIFIED BY " + password_Of_User + " ACCOUNT UNLOCK
```

Where `iD_Of_User` and `password_Of_User` definitely come in directly from an HTTP request.

This is a pretty textbook SQL injection risk-- we're passing incoming, untrusted data directly to a query. However, when I try to parameterize the query-- I get an error when I try to use a PreparedStatement object to parameterize the dynamic values... I guess PreparedStatement's parameters can only be used for data values? And the ALTER query here is not using the values that way.

I don't think input validation is even possible here-- maybe on the `iD_Of_User` value, but almost certainly not on the `password_Of_User` value (which is sometimes used as a password reset-- so it's only restrictions are the Oracle 12c password standards).

Any help were would be greatly appreciated. I reviewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49253300/sql-injection-prevention-with-dynamic-sql-alter-user-query) post, but it didn't give me a good solution. I'm hoping someone knows of a good way to do password resets/account unlocks in Oracle which doesn't open the app up to SQL injection.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is cross-posted

Comment: Please do not cross-post. If required, the other stack might migrate it here.

Comment: Is migrating something I can do/trigger myself?  It seems like this is a more active site for secure coding than stackoverflow.

Comment: you can flag your posts for migration

Comment: You cannot do this, for the reason that ALTER USER isn’t a query so it doesn’t go through the query planner so PreparedStatement is irrelevant. You can validate the username using a PreparedStatement however (SELECT FROM dba_users). And instead of accepting a new password you could generate a new one and tell the user what it is. If someone wants to unlock this question I’ll post this as the answer.

Comment: This question could also be reopened if reworded like "How can an attacker use SQL injection in ALTER query?/What can an attacker do with an injectable ALTER statement?" or so, like https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44151/sql-injection-with-insert-statement does If reworded this way, then it should be reopened IMO : migrating it seems a bad idea, as I (we?) wouldn't answer the "right way to code this", but we would answer the "how can this be exploited" (thos there is a fun way to exploit this query :) )

Comment: @schroeder Hi!  Do you think that following @ Xeno's recommendation here might make it so this post could be re-opened?  I've tried to model it more after what they recommended.  What @ Gaius said is very interesting to me-- I'd like to respond back them and work through it.